# Getting internal server error 500 while displaying output in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have just started learning Flask and referring a tutorial to run a small piece of test code.

Here is the code:

**Hello.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
   return render_template('student.html')

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      return render_template("result.html",result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

**student.html**

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/result" method = "POST">
         <p>Name <input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
         <p>Physics <input type = "text" name = "Physics" /></p>
         <p>Chemistry <input type = "text" name = "chemistry" /></p>
         <p>Maths <input type ="text" name = "Mathematics" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <table border = 1>
         {% for key, value in result.iteritems() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

I have kept `student.html` and `result.html` in `templates` folder. Upon running `Hello.py`, `student.html` runs and displays a form in which I could enter the values in the fields. Clicking Submit should display `result.html` page but instead, it gives the following error:

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.**

Traceback:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2017 20:48:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2017-06-25 20:48:24,634] ERROR in app: Exception on /result [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "<ipython-input-1-0b3c292b941b>", line 12, in result
    return render_template("result.html",result = result)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kshitiz\Desktop\doc2vec\templates\result.html", line 6, in top-level template code
    {% for key, value in result.iteritems() %}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict object' has no attribute 'iteritems'
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2017 20:48:24] "POST /result HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Could you please tell what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Not without the traceback. In the post you deleted, you included it but there you had a `TemplateNotFound` exception. Do you still have that same exception? Then fix your template file by moving it in the right location.

Comment: I realized how stupid I was to do that mistake. I moved both the result.html and student.html in templates folder and there was no exception. Instead this. One scripts works while the other don't.

Comment: We still need to see the traceback however.

Comment: I am sorry but how do I get the traceback?

Comment: Ok I got it. My bad. I will edit the question and put traceback.

Comment: Don't use `iteritems()`; use `items()`. Jinja is almost but not quite Python, and you have a `ImmutableMultiDict` object that doesn't implement that method.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed in the `request.form` object to your template. As the traceback tells you, that object has no `iteritems()` method:

```
'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict object' has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

The `iteritems()` methods on dictionaries are Python 2 specific; in Python 3, just use `items()`:

```
{% for key, value in result.items() %}
```